# Google Maps API Static Map off-road marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

When I place a marker with geocode on a off road position, Google always put the marker on the road.
Example:

```
<http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?\zoom=17&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|52%2006.761,%205%2008.347&sensor=false>
```

In the normal Google maps you see the original position (the green arrow) and the position where the marker is placed: http://g.co/maps/wc4vg

How can I get the marker off the road? So I want my marker to be at the place of the green arrow in my Google Maps API.

Maybe it is not possible with the Static Map, but if so, is it possible with V3 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LatLng(52.112683,5.138950) instead of the address: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=17&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|52.112683,5.138950&sensor=false